# Syntax Error unexpected Token u Json error

Tags: php, ajax, json, yui

I am calling a YUI function to get status message from a php function that return the proper status in json format.

when i trigger the event in gives the error message :-

"Syntax error unexpected token u"

Here is the source :-

```
 var ajax_url = 'initcalls.php?action=ping';
 var pngbtn = Y.one('#id_solr_btn_ping');
    pngbtn.on('click', function(e) {

          Y.one('#solr_ping_status').setHTML('&nbsp;<img src="pix/ajax-circle.gif">');
          Y.io(ajax_url, {
            on : {
                success : function(data) {
        try
        {
              var resp = Y.JSON.parse(data.responseText);
                    }
        catch (e)
                     {
                           alert(e);
                           return;
                     }
        if (resp.status == 'ok') {
           Y.one('#solr_ping_status').setHTML('&nbsp;<img src="pix/success.png">');
           timeout("clearSaveStatus('#solr_ping_status')",2000);
        }
        else {
        Y.one('#solr_ping_status').setHTML('&nbsp;<img src="pix/warning.png">');
        }}
        }
              });

            return false; 

           });
```

My php file return the following result:-

```
     {"status":"ok"}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the exact complete response as contained in `data.responseText` is `{"status": "ok"}`? Seems like PHP may be sending something else, an error message perhaps.

Comment: I tried with this simple php page & its return exactly what we should expect.<?php
                 $arr = array();
                 $arr['status']='ok';
                print(json_encode($arr));
         exit();
         ?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Callbacks for `Y.io` receive two parameters: the id of the transaction and the response object in the second parameter:

```
Y.io(url, {
  on: {
    success: function (id, response) {
      // ...
    }
  }
});
```

The error you're getting is probably because you're accessing the `responseText` property of `id` which is undefined. The undefined value gets coerced to the `"undefined"` string and `JSON.parse` throws when encountering the `u` in "undefined".

You just need to use the second parameter as your `data` object.

Comment: Is their any way to pass a array of parameter to be used inside php file ??? except in the GET request URL?

Comment: Yes, there is a `data` property you can add to the configuration object of your IO request that sends parameters to the server. You should read [the IO User Guide](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/io/#the-configuration-object).